# AJAX POST Servlet call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to POST URL exact like this to next page.

http://localhost:9000/favorite.json?url1=/offers/singapore-rugby-7s&url2=/offers/limited-time-offer-save-up-to-40&url3=/offers/rejoice-this-easter&url4=/06-offers-detail

Below code will work? Not sure whether my method is correct.

```
var formattedFavouriteOffer = '?url1=/offers/singapore-rugby-7s&url2=/offers/limited-time-offer-save-up-to-40&url3=/offers/rejoice-this-easter&url4=/06-offers-detail';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:9000/favorite.json" +formattedFavouriteOffer,
    data: formattedFavouriteOffer,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(resultData) { 
        alert("Save Complete"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: If you need to post you do not need to add `formattedFavouriteOffer`. But what response are you expecting from a `.json` file?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Our backend team having this path "http://localhost:9000/favorite.json" inside data-endpoint attribute on next page. I need to include ?url1=/offers/singapore-rugby-7s&url2=/offers/limited-time-offer-save-up-to-40&url3=&url4=&url5=&url6= this output with path name inside data-endpoint attribute via POST method